# word "ART" is converting into timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I am breaking words and converting each word to timestamp and if it is converted then I am proceeding my string to next level. However, there is a string and I have word "Art" in it and it is getting converted as well.

Here is my code

```
$brokenTitle = "Art Brut";
if(strtotime($brokenTitle)!== false){
    echo "2\t$brokenTitle\t";
    echo "strtotime\t".strtotime($brokenTitle)."\n";
    unset($explodeTitle[$key]);
}
```

My output

```
   2    Art Brut    strtotime   1546584316
```

I am not sure what is happening. I am using centOs 7 and php version is 5.6.38. If I am running it online then it correctly making it false but here it is converting it.

It is converting the specific word "Art", it is not converting brut when saparated. How to stop that from being converted?

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @Andrei OP says they are using `5.6.38`

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't notice that. It seems that any version bellow `7.2.x` exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: My timezone is set to Chicago.

Comment: Doesn't matter what timezone you've set. `Art` is the ART – Argentina Time (Standard Time).

Comment: Ok.. NOw we know the reason... please let me know how to stop this from converting?

Comment: @RahulGupta if you add that question to your question, then I think the duplicate is not valid as it doesn't mention how to prevent it. That should be a valid reason to reopen the question in my opinion

Comment: Well I suppose you could not use `strtotime`. More of a wokraround rather than an actual solution.

Comment: My entire title contain date as well separated by dot, so I explode with dot and check each word into the strtotime and if it is returning then I unset that word. For exapmle: My word is Art Brut . Time Square . 17 January and I am having so many title like that, By doing strtotime, I am able to achieve the task but here I stuck.

Comment: So your string is `Art Brut . Time Square . 17 January` and you want to extract `17 January` and use strtotime on it?

Comment: yes... but position of 17 january is not always same... it could be anywhere in the string

Comment: @PaulCrovella I think the duplicate is not correct for this question. The duplicate does explain why, but doesn't explain how to avoid it or answer what OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: @PaulCrovella there are countless questions that does not have a clear question. But that is not the point. The duplicate does **not in any way** answer OPs question, before or after the his edit.

Comment: @PaulCrovella as I see it there is a underlying question in the question, which is how do I stop this from happening. After the edit the question is added as the last line.

Comment: @PaulCrovella And the reopen button is for what purpose then?